# Is it possible to access Request object from Global.asa file?

Tags: asp-classic

I need to get access to some server variables like `APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH` from the the `Global.asa` file.  I can do this on any page of my site using the `Request` object as follows...

```
Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")
```

But I don't seem to have access to the `Request` object within the `Global.asa` file.  Is there an equivalent call I can do here with the `Server` object?

Answer (score 4):

Well I've found an alternative for what I want to do.  I can get the equivalent of...

```
Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")
```

by using

```
Server.MapPath("./")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if vartype(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))=8 then
    'xxxx'
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Long and now unneccessary suggestion follows. Didn't want to trash it :-p

Since one Application instance can include several virtual directories which would map to different physical paths, you can't get the exact same.
Probably you could find an automation object (*) to install in your server, then make an instance (for example with Server.CreateObject) and interrogate it for the path to the main application, i.e. ignoring any virtual directories.

(*) Suggested automation objects; something that can read the IIS Metabase.